# GatsbyJS: Adding Files that Do NOT Get Turned Into Pages in the Pages Folder

Tags: gatsby

Is there a way to add a file in the `pages` directory in Gatsby and not have it turn into a page?

For instance, let's say that I have a contact page which has a contact form.  I would like to create a contact folder, which has within it an `index.js` file as well as a `contact-form.js` file.  I.e., a structure like this:

```
src
- pages
 - contact
  - index.js
  - contact-form.js
```

The idea is that that the `index.js` file would import the contact form component from the `contact-form.js` file.  But there would **not** be a `contact/contact-us` page.

Is there some way to do this with Gatsby?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `gatsby-plugin-page-creator` [docs](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/packages/gatsby-plugin-page-creator/) files matching the following patterns are excluded:

```
template-*
__tests__/*
*.test.jsx?
*.spec.jsx?
*.d.tsx?
*.json
*.yaml
_*
.*
```

Try renaming your file to `_contact-form.js`.

However I would avoid that altogether and have a dedicated folder for components say `src/components`. Going further I set a webpack alias to `src` directory so my imports could look like `import PartialComp from "@/components/PartialComp.jsx"` no matter where the import originates from.

Comment: Thanks -- that is what I was looking for.  In terms of a components folder -- I do have a components folder.  But I like to save that for general components that are used among multiple pages.  For a component that is specific to one page, I like to organize that component together with the relevant page.  Either way -- thanks for the help and the link.